# Show template Proposal error in eclipse Neon.1

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse Neon.1 showing this error when Ctrl + Space press for auto completion.

Failed to download jre:jre:call:zip:1.0.0
String index out of range: -1

Comment: In Eclipse Neon. 1 showing this error can any one give suggestion to resolved this issue.